# Sql logic needed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Hello People I have two tables...

```
Users
- id (
- username

sample data (1:alex,2:rocky,3:kothi)



linked_table
- from_id
- to_id
sample data (1:2,1:3)
```

I want to fetch and display from_name and To_name from linked_table.i tried joining and selecting but it fetches only from_name

```
    $Get_Linked_name = \DB::table('linked_table')
    ->join('users','linked_table.from_id','=','users.Id')
    ->where(array('linked_table.from_id'=>1))
    ->select()->get();
```

`'linked_table.from_id'=>1` is linked to `2,3` now i want to fetch `username` of `2,3` i know it can be done using  another empty array and `foreach loop` but is there any other better options?

`updated: From_name and To_name are nothing but username of users table`

Comment: Where is your from_name and to_name field in linked_table? All i see is from_id,  to_id and date field.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes From_name and To_name are nothing but `username` of users table

Comment: is it possible to post sample data of two tables?

Comment: @ William Francis Gomes updated

Comment: Because you are joining only from_id. To get result against to_id, you need to join that field too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION`

```
SELECT u.id, u.username
FROM Users u, JOIN linked_table lt
ON u.id = lt.from_id
WHERE lt.from_id = 1
UNION
SELECT u.id, u.username
FROM Users u, JOIN linked_table lt
ON u.id = lt.to_id
WHERE lt.from_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query:

```
SELECT from.username as From_name, to.username as To_name
FROM   Users from, Users to, linked_table lt
WHERE  from.id = lt.from_id
       AND to.id = lt.to_id
       AND from.id = 1
```